# How do you set a TextView of a fragment in a ViewPager from the MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I have a method called changeText() in the First-fragment, I am getting a null pointer exception on the TextView when i call it from MainActivity. However if I call it from the onCreate() in the Fragment class it works.

Any help would be great.

### How I call it from Activity

```
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    int index = pager.getCurrentItem();
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = ((MyPagerAdapter)pager.getAdapter());
    FirstFragment fragment = (FirstFragment) adapter.getItem(index);


    fragment.changeText("dssf");
```

### Fragment class

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

TextView frv;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);

     frv=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);




    return v;
}

public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

    FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}

public void changeText(String text){
    //frv=(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);

    frv.setText(text);
}}
```

Thanks in advance.

edit**

Error im getting

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.example.//.slider.FirstFragment.changeText(FirstFragment.java:45)
                                                   at com.example.//.slider.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
```

Comment: Add the stack trace.  Either the Fragment or the TextView are null.

Comment: The `TextView` must be inflated before you can set the text. Which means `onCreateView` of your fragment must be called before you try and manipulate the `TextView`. In your code above, it looks like you are retrieving a `FirstFragment` from your adapter, but that doesn't mean it's inflated and visible to the user. Is that fragment visible or is it just stored in the adapter?

Comment: Just did a test and the fragment is not visible to the user! also added the error.

Comment: commit your fragmetn first FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.your_placehodler, new YourFragment());
ft.commit();